# Какую cms выбрать для проекта?

Tags: cms

Надо реализовать сайт, в котором примерно следующий функционал.

1. Есть пользователи, которые бьются по категориям, например "репетитор по математике, репетитор по физике" или "хирург, медсестра, уролог", т.е. люди разных профессий, но из одной сферы.
2. Все эти люди добавляются в каталог, можно смотреть их анкеты, выбирать, сравнивать параметры (к примеру стаж работы или ученая степень, любые опции)
3. Если я выбрал репетитора, врача, или сисадмина, можно ему задать пару вопросов в чат, личку, имэйл
4. Поиск пользователей по сайту
5. Регистрация пользователей в каталог

Какую cms выбрать? Важно написать все как можно быстрее, поэтому решили делать на какой-то cms и собрать сайт на готовых модулях. Поэтому кроме названия cms хочется также услышать модули, которые можно задействовать, спасибо.

Comment: >Важно написать все как можно быстрее

получится уродство. Нельзя так подходить к разработке сайта + не вижу ни одного слова про дизайн сайта!

Comment: А какая приоритетнее, платная или бесплатная?

Comment: Задача сделать до 13 мая. Важно чтобы работал и не важно как. Потом его будут допиливать до нужного уровня. Шеф реально ПОСПОРИЛ, и надо теперь тупо сделать, чтобы выйграть спор, а потом уже делать шедевр или не делать.

Comment: > А какая приоритетнее, платная или бесплатная?
любая

Comment: @butteff, глупый спор. Реально.

Comment: Я просто работаю программистом, реализую поставленные задачи, ведь, проблемы негров (сотрудников), как говорится, шерифа не еб*т

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, подходит [Drupal](http://drupal.org).

1. Модуль CCk (7 версий уже встроено в систему). Создаете новый тип, и добавляете какие нужно типы полей. Очень просто, для категорий воспользуйтесь таксономией.
2. [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) и многое другое.
3. Views

Answer (score 1):

Ну если любая, то посоветую [SLAED CMS](http://www.slaed.net). Без описания излишеств и прочего... Есть платная и бесплатная версии. Плюсы и минусы подчеркивайте для себя на официальном сайте.

P.S. Легко дорабатываемая.

Comment: А модули то какие для реализации нужного мне функционала?

Comment: Мне сейчас бросить все и искать вам модули? их там более 200 штук...